# Running a filter (!) command in visual mode

Tags: vim

Let's say I'm running the following filter command in vim:

```
:!ls
```

If running it in normal mode, it will basically open up a new screen and display the output of that command.

However, if I run it in visual mode, it will insert whatever the output of the command is into the current visual selection (replacing what was there previously, if there was anything).

Why is there this different behavior in the two? Is there a place in the help section that explains a bit more about the mechanics of filter commands? `:h :!` says a bit but doesn't say anything about the different modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press `:` in Visual mode then the bookmarks `:'<,'>` are added automatically to the command-line. And so instead of `:!cmd` (which is explained under `:h :!`) you get `:'<,'>!cmd` which is discussed under `:h :range!`.

Just press `:h c_CTRL-U` to delete that range from the command line if you don't need it.